# How haproxy uses sni to spread traffic？

Tags: haproxy

My configuration is as follows, currently the web site works fine, I also have a public ip with an ssl certificate, it doesn't work,It is routed to the web site when requested, is there any way to fix it? Thanks

```
acl is_a01 ssl_fc_sni -i test.xyz
acl is_a02 ssl_fc_sni -i 12.13.14.16

use_backend n1 if is_a01
use_backend n2 if is_a02
default_backend web
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite good description on this blog post [Enhanced SSL Load Balancing with Server Name Indication (SNI) TLS Extension](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/enhanced-ssl-load-balancing-with-server-name-indication-sni-tls-extension/).
In the documentation is this the keyword you are searching for [req.ssl_sni](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.6/configuration.html#req.ssl_sni)

Here is a untested snipplet from your question

```
# Wait for a client hello for at most 5 seconds
tcp-request inspect-delay 5s

# optionaly check if it's ssl_hello_type 1
tcp-request content accept if { req.ssl_hello_type 1 }

# The test values (test.xyz,12.13.14.16) *MUST*
# be in the certificate
acl is_a01 req.ssl_sni -i test.xyz
acl is_a02 req.ssl_sni -i 12.13.14.16

use_backend n1 if is_a01
use_backend n2 if is_a02
default_backend web
```