# HAProxy redirect HTTP in mode tcp

Tags: http, ssl, haproxy

I'm trying to redirect HTTP-requests on a given port but keep getting error SSL Handshake failure.

In HAProxy 2.2.25 I have a quite similar setup that works (but does not terminate the SSL).

```
frontend smqtt
    bind :8883
    mode tcp
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content capture req.proto_http len 1
    use_backend port_check if HTTP
    default_backend smqtt-broker
backend smqtt-broker
    mode tcp
    server Broker1 <ip-address> check
backend port_check
    mode http
    http-request return content-type "text/plain" string "Port Check Success"
```

When I try a similar setup in HAProxy 2.6.9 it doesn't work (but has TLS termination)

```
frontend smqtt
    bind :8883 ssl crt <path_to_crt> verify required ca-file <path_to_ca>
    mode tcp
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content capture req.proto_http len 1
    use_backend port_check if HTTP
    default_backend brokers
backend port_check
    mode http
    http-request return content-type "text/plain" string "Port Check Success"
backend brokers
    mode tcp
    server Broker1 <ip-address> check
```

The setup is almost identical except that the first one isn't terminating the TLS-connection and the second one IS terminating the TLS.

Any idea how to redirect the HTTP-requests given?

Answer (score 0):

The [Pre-defined ACL HTTP](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.6/configuration.html#7.4) is defined as `req.proto_http` which implies that HAProxy have to decrypt the TLS and start to analyze the request which will not be done in TCP mode.

From my point of view have you several options

1. Route the requests based on SNI header as answered in [How haproxy uses sni to spread traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953087/6778826), my preferred solution.
2. Add another frontend in http mode and use this.
3. add a further bind line in the tcp frontend which is plain text